# GCP: Generic routine to create IAM Policy Binding given a resource, member, and role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have a dump of IAM Policies and I want to add a new member to *all* of them.  The problem is that each resource has its own API for setting IAM policies, and so I would need to handle each type of resource individually.  So much toil.  I want a generic "IAM API" that takes a resource & policy as inputs, and creates the binding.  Is such a thing possible?

For reference, the format for my policy dump is:

```
- policy:
    bindings:
    - members:
      - user:tom@email.com
      role: roles/compute.networkUser
    etag: BwWfgKQuAFg=
  project: projects/800307802527
  resource: //compute.googleapis.com/projects/foo-proj/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/sub1
```

I have a very long list of these records, and I want to iterate through them adding a member "new-member@email.com" to each one.  Is there a generic IAM API I can call to add a policy binding to a resource?

Comment: Each resource has its own API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, each resource has its own API. There is no "Generic" IAM API to handle your use case. You can however create a feature request through the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=1162687&hl=th) to make a request for this feature to be implemented.

Comment: Well, that's that.